# How to reduce the impact of changing the value of the `fpath` array on zsh starting time?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm using `zsh` version `5.1.1` and `tmux` version `2.3`, and recently I've noticed that starting a new shell (via a new window or pane in `tmux`) takes more time than before.

It's enough for me to type around 5 characters before the prompt is displayed. I would like to reduce this time, so I wrote a `return` statement at various positions inside my `zshrc` file until I found the line which was responsible for the increased starting time. It seems to be:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)
```

And I can reproduce my issue with the following minimal `zshrc`:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

The first line prepends the path `~/.zsh/completion` to the array `fpath`. I do this because I want to write the files containing the code of my custom completion functions inside this directory.

To get a sense of how much time it takes for a shell to start, I found this command:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do /usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit; done
```

It starts and exits 10 shells consecutively, each time measuring the time it took. Here's what it reports with the previous minimal `zshrc`:

```
0.36user 0.04system 0:00.42elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6056maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+9087minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.30user 0.04system 0:00.36elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5900maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+8949minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.30user 0.05system 0:00.37elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6080maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+8992minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.31user 0.04system 0:00.37elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5936maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+8956minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.30user 0.04system 0:00.36elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6052maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+9089minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.32user 0.04system 0:00.38elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5944maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+8948minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.32user 0.04system 0:00.37elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6004maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+8991minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.32user 0.02system 0:00.36elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6056maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+9109minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.30user 0.05system 0:00.36elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6072maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+9003minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.31user 0.04system 0:00.36elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6040maxresident)k
0inputs+160outputs (0major+9055minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I'm not sure to read this correctly, but it seems to indicate that on average a shell needs `0.32` second to start.

Here's what the same command produces with the same minimal `zshrc` after commenting the line `fpath=(...)` :

```
0.08user 0.02system 0:00.10elapsed 97%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5608maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1721minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.06user 0.00system 0:00.07elapsed 97%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5660maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1723minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.05user 0.00system 0:00.06elapsed 92%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5680maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1720minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.05user 0.00system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5724maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1734minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.04user 0.02system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5748maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1730minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.05user 0.00system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5692maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1724minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.04user 0.01system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5636maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1728minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.04user 0.01system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5628maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1727minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.04user 0.01system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5684maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1722minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.05user 0.00system 0:00.06elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5728maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1731minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Now, on average, it seems to take only `0.05` second.

By default, the value of `FPATH` is:

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions:/usr/share/zsh/vendor-functions:/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Calendar:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Chpwd:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/AIX:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/BSD:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Base:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Cygwin:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Darwin:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Debian:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Linux:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Mandriva:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Redhat:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Solaris:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/X:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Zsh:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/openSUSE:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Exceptions:/usr/share/zsh/functions/MIME:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Newuser:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts:/usr/share/zsh/functions/TCP:/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info:/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info/Backends:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zftp:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zle
```

At the beginning of the variable, I noticed the path `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`.
It was an empty directory, so I removed it and replaced it with a symbolic link whose target is my completion directory:

```
cd /usr/local/share/zsh; sudo rm site-functions; sudo ln -s ~/.zsh/completion site-functions
```

With this symbolic link, I don't need to change the value of `fpath`.
The completion functions still work, and the starting time of the shells has been divided by `4`, from around `0.32` second to around `0.08` second. The difference is noticeable to me. However, it doesn't feel right to use a system-wide directory.

Is there another, better, way to achieve the same result?

---

Edit:

Thanks to [@thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370040/how-to-store-zsh-completion-functions-inside-a-dropbox-directory-without-increas#comment657937_370040), I've realised that my `~/.zsh/` directory was in fact a symbolic link to a Dropbox directory:

```
ls -l .zsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 16 jan. 18 18:54 .zsh -> Dropbox/conf/zsh
```

I did this to have a backup of my configuration, and because I don't know how to use git.

If I move the completion functions to a directory outside Dropbox, `zsh` starting time becomes much lower.

---

Edit 2:

I don't understand, now it seems `zsh` starts slowly again, even if I put my completion functions outside of the Dropbox directory.

In case it helps, I have uploaded on a pastebin-like site the output of the following command:

```
strace -e trace=desc -o log -r zsh
```

According to `man strace`, the `-e trace=desc` option should trace all file descriptor related system calls. And the `-r` option should print a relative timestamp upon entry to each system call.

Here's a link for the log when [`fpath` is unchanged](https://www.zerobin.net/?b09d0556c53a22d8#rFxIOC+T1Ou4P5eFrLDxf87ECcUhaiwM8lAs1sELyzM=).
And here's a 2nd link for the log when [`fpath` is changed](https://www.zerobin.net/?9bb73e944d7f70f0#fvz+YFxt+3iS7rDaDNdwcXFc8fmsZIN4uExEMkyrn50=).

I'm unable to interpret the log files, however there's a big difference in size. The first one seems to include around only `4000` system calls, while the 2nd one has around `67000`.

---

Edit 3:

I also recorded the output of the following command:

```
PS4='+[%D{%H:%M:%S.%.}]%N:%i> ' zsh -x
```

… with the `script` utility.

Here's a link to the log file when [`fpath` is unchanged](https://www.zerobin.net/?952a934438e5d5e2#b7/nstnDzTZhGGUIgOLLJ54DQNywNFOa+s4gUmkVTFw=).
And here's a link to the log file when [`fpath` is changed](https://www.zerobin.net/?d4386c4584ce925f#nY/Z2kMpWZKc1TTbZ/fg1JVeoF108Z0qhGuDWOGx22o=).

This time, the first log file has only around `600` lines, while the second one has around `100000` lines.

In the log file where `fpath` is changed, the functions which are called most often are `compdef` (around `69000` times), `compinit` (around `16000` times), and `compdump` (around `14000` times).

Thank you for all the help given in the comments.

Comment: That user time is unusually high, though I cannot reproduce your results with `repeat 10 =time zsh -i -c exit` on ZSH 5.3.1 on Centos7. How many files do you have in `~/.zsh/completion` ?

Comment: @thrig Thank you very much. I only have 5 small files inside `~/.zsh/completion`. However, your comment helped me understand that it wasn't a problem with my `zshrc`, but with the directory itself. I've just realised that in fact, it was a symlink to a directory stored inside Dropbox. If I move the completion functions to a directory outside Dropbox, the times get much lower. I should probably stop using Dropbox. I will once I know how to better use git. It's weird though, my `zshrc` is also symlinked to a Dropbox file, and it doesn't seem to cause any issue.

Comment: Is all I/O slow with Dropbox, or just ZSH? If just ZSH, that might be something worth reporting to the zsh-workers mailing list.

Comment: @thrig I have a lot of configuration files in the Dropbox directory (for bash, zsh, vim, tmux) and I didn't notice anything unusually slow, except for the zsh completion functions. But maybe I'm wrong, I don't know how to measure all I/O activity inside the Dropbox directory, and compare the results to what happens in `/home/user`. But you're right, there may be something worth reporting. Once I find how to get some data, I'll try to update the question, and if the results only concern zsh, I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Slow I/O would normally jack up system time (blocked on wait) so this is likely something internal to ZSH. It may also depend on the exact system calls ZSH is using. What does a `strace -e trace=desc -o blah -r zsh ...` for Dropbox versus not loads? This should trace file descriptor related calls and print relative timestamps.

Comment: @thrig I'm sorry, I'm not sure Dropbox is the issue, because now it seems `zsh` starts slowly even after moving the completion files outside of it. I've updated the question with the output of your commands. The output when `fpath` is modified is huge (the weight of the log file was around `3.5` MB), I had a hard time finding a site to upload it without exceeding a restriction.

Comment: See also `PS4='+[%D{%H:%M:%S.%.}]%N:%i> ' zsh -x` to profile your shell startup. (maybe run under `script` to save the output)

Answer (score 1):

I thought that maybe the problem came from my zsh version, so I purged the `zsh` package and compiled it from source:

```
% sudo aptitude install git-core gcc make autoconf yodl libncursesw5-dev texinfo

% git clone git://zsh.git.sf.net/gitroot/zsh/zsh
% cd zsh
% git checkout zsh-5.3.1

% ./Util/preconfig

% ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu \
--prefix=/usr \
--includedir=/usr/include \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--sysconfdir=/etc \
--localstatedir=/var \
--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--libexecdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--bindir=/bin \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -g" \
--enable-maildir-support \
--enable-etcdir=/etc/zsh \
--enable-function-subdirs \
--enable-site-fndir=/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions \
--enable-fndir=/usr/share/zsh/functions \
--with-tcsetpgrp \
--with-term-lib="ncursesw tinfo" \
--enable-cap \
--enable-pcre \
--enable-readnullcmd=pager \
--enable-custom-patchlevel=Debian \
--enable-additional-fpath=/usr/share/zsh/vendor-functions,/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions \
--disable-ansi2knr
```

I found the dependencies and the configuration options by reading the `INSTALL` file as well as this gist found with Google:

```
https://gist.github.com/nicoulaj/715855
```

… and by looking at how the Ubuntu devs compiled the latest `zsh` packages:

```
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/280509421/buildlog_ubuntu-yakkety-amd64.zsh_5.2-5ubuntu1_BUILDING.txt.gz
```

There were some options which were written twice, or were not recognized by zsh, so I removed them.
The value that the Ubuntu devs gave to `LDFLAGS` didn't seem to work on my machine, so I copied
the one from the gist on Github. The options I kept are described by `./configure --help`:

```
--build=BUILD           configure for building on BUILD [guessed]

--prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                        [/usr/local]

--includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]

--mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]

--infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]

--sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]

--localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]

--libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]

--libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]

--bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]

 LDFLAGS                linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
                            nonstandard directory <lib dir>

--enable-maildir-support
                        enable maildir support in MAIL and MAILPATH

--enable-etcdir=DIR     the default directory for global zsh scripts

--enable-function-subdirs
                        install functions in subdirectories

--enable-site-fndir=DIR same for site functions (not version specific)

--enable-fndir=DIR      the directory in which to install functions

--with-tcsetpgrp        assumes that tcsetpgrp() exists and works correctly

 --with-term-lib=LIBS   search space-separated LIBS for terminal handling

 --enable-cap           enable the search for POSIX capabilities (may
                        require additional headers to be added by hand)

--enable-pcre           enable the search for the pcre library (may create
                        run-time library dependencies)

--enable-readnullcmd=PAGER
                        pager used when READNULLCMD is not set

--enable-custom-patchlevel
                        set a custom ZSH_PATCHLEVEL value

--enable-additional-fpath=DIR
                        add directories to default function path

--enable-ansi2knr       translate source to K&R C before compiling
```

The compilation worked, but there were 2 failures among the 48 tests performed by the `make check` command:

```
% make
% make check
…
**************************************
46 successful test scripts, 2 failures, 0 skipped
**************************************
Makefile:187: recipe for target 'check' failed
make[1]: *** [check] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/GitRepos/zsh/Test'
Makefile:263: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

I couldn't get rid of them.

Finally, instead of using `make install` to install the binary, I used `checkinstall` to have a `.deb` that I can
remove if I need to change the shell in the future (with a `dpkg -r zsh`):

```
% sudo checkinstall
```

During the installation, I had to give a short description (I used `shell with lots of features`),
and more importantly I had to give a version. Without a version compatible with Debian policy,
`checkinstall` wouldn't generate a `.deb`. I looked at the output of `apt-cache policy zsh` to check
what is the naming scheme used by Debian, and chose `5.3.1-1ubuntu2`.

```
% echo /bin/zsh >> /etc/shells
% chsh  →  /bin/zsh
```

These 2 lines were necessary to make Ubuntu recognize `/bin/zsh` as a valid login shell, and to make it my default shell.

Now, the shell version is `5.3.1` (instead of `5.1.1`):

```
% zsh --version
    zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

And the shell starts quickly (around `0.04s`):

```
% repeat 10 =time zsh -i -c exit

    0.06user 0.03system 0:00.12elapsed 80%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5592maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5668minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.06user 0.01system 0:00.09elapsed 77%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5480maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5634minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.04user 0.01system 0:00.07elapsed 82%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5736maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5641minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.04user 0.01system 0:00.07elapsed 77%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5652maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5645minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.03user 0.03system 0:00.07elapsed 82%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5736maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5634minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.04user 0.01system 0:00.07elapsed 78%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5548maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5624minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.04user 0.02system 0:00.07elapsed 78%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5612maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5655minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.04user 0.01system 0:00.07elapsed 77%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5780maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5624minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.03user 0.02system 0:00.07elapsed 78%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5584maxresident)k
    0inputs+0outputs (0major+5641minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    0.03user 0.02system 0:00.07elapsed 78%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5668maxresident)k
```

The first time I compiled, I forgot to switch to the latest release branch, so I was on `master`.
This development version of `zsh` had an even worse starting time than the version from the Ubuntu repositories.
Around `0.42s` to start a shell. But again, only if I added a directory to `fpath` in `zshrc`, and created a file inside the latter (a simple `touch file` was enough).

So I wonder whether the problem came from the compilation options, or the release version.
I hope the release version I have compiled will remain quick…

Thank you [@thrigh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370040/how-to-reduce-the-impact-of-changing-the-value-of-the-fpath-array-on-zsh-start#comment658189_370040) and [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370040/how-to-reduce-the-impact-of-changing-the-value-of-the-fpath-array-on-zsh-start#comment658240_370040) for helping me in the comments.